# Test 32-bit assembly on a 64 bit windows with NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm using C# and .NET 4.0 to build my current application. For unit testing I use [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) in its latest version.

In my application I have to make use of a 32-bit DLL, and therefore I have to create the assembly with target 'x86'.

The application itself works fine under both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, but I can't use NUnit as I get the following exception upon loading the 'x86' assembly:

In Settings->Assembly Isolation I use 'Run tests in separate process per Assembly', but to no use.

```
System.BadImageFormatException...

Server stack trace: 
   bei System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   bei System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   bei System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   bei NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   bei NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   bei NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   bei NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bei NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Util.RemoteTestAgent.AgentRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bei NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Util.AggregatingTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

How to get those tests running on a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105398/how-do-i-investigate-the-course-of-a-tests-assembly-refusing-to-load-in-nunit   (nunit-x86.exe worked for me)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't find this one on in the search. Please make it an answer so I can upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered in *[How do I investigate the course of a test's assembly refusing to load in NUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105398)*. (Ref Ian Ringrose's comment to the question.)