# nunit not working in windows 7 at all

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit, windows-7-x64, nunit-2.5

I am new to unit testing and this ism y first time trying NUnit.

My environment is windows 7 professional 64 bit, visual studio 2010 and i am working on a windows application in C#. I just wrote a single test and i am trying to run the test using NUnit GUI.

My NUnit version is 2.5.10, i also tried 4 other versions below this and i get the same error.

the error is

> "System.BadImageFormatException: could not load file or assembly 'DataLogger, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> You may be attempting to load an assembly built with a later version of the CLR than the version under which NUnit is currently running(2.0.50727) or trying to load a 64-bit assembly into a 32-bit process.
>
> For further information, use the Exception Details menu item."

What i did is i loaded the application exe in the debug folder of the project into the NUnit GUI. (i mentioned this because i have a doubt that this could be the wrong way). Any help on this would be useful for me.

Comment: Have you tried writing a very simple test, including none of your application code? Is DataLogger part of your application code?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105398/how-do-i-investigate-the-course-of-a-tests-assembly-refusing-to-load-in-nunit

Comment: Do you have any unmanged code in your system?  If so, check for 32/64 issules.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I faced this problem myself. 
You need to use the x86 version of the application which is usually located at
C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\nunit-x86.exe
And that does not throw the exception.

Comment: .... why I have to use 32bit version of Nunit when my machine is 64bit. complete pain in the neck. Worked like a charm tho, thx.

Answer (score 2):

I read somewhere that if we use  windows 7 64 bit and developing apps for x86 then a separate GUi called nunitx86.exe in the same folder must be used. I did that and it works.